# Sample all combinations of n rows in R

Tags: r, combinations, subset, sample

I want to take all possible samples of n=3 rows from a data frame. I can obtain all those row combinations using:

```
Combinations <- combn(dim(df)[1], 3)

Combinations[1:10]
 [1] 1 2 3 1 2 4 1 2 5 1
```

I would need to take subsets of every 3 numbers I get in `Combinations` and use them for the row numbers of the `df` (i,e. first one is rows 1 2 3; second is 1 2 4, and so on).

I also need to 'store' each subset to perform functions (obtain sum and mean of the columns and save the row.names). I am using a list for that purpose which would store all samples of the original dataframe.

Here's an example of a function using `sample` which makes what I need but not for every combination.

```
take_sample = function(dataframe){
    df2=  dataframe[sample(nrow(dataframe),3),]  
    lista=list(filas=row.names(df2),
               suma=sum(dist(df2)),
              coord_mean=apply(df2,2,mean))
    return(lista)
    }
```

Here's the df

```
structure(list(x = c(4817.5, 4814.5, 4817.5, 8515, 8518, 8543.5, 
8549.5, 7236.5, 7242.5, 8024.5, 8017, 5549, 5547, 8857, 8861.5, 
8132.5, 8136.5, 9349, 9343, 5914), y = c(4424, 4431.5, 4432, 
4482.5, 4484, 4574.5, 4576, 4758, 4759.5, 4772, 4772.5, 4807.5, 
4809.5, 4936, 4940, 5177, 5175, 5192.5, 5192.5, 5236)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(1175L, 1176L, 1177L, 1180L, 1181L, 1185L, 
1187L, 1203L, 1204L, 1206L, 1207L, 1215L, 1217L, 1227L, 1229L, 
1249L, 1250L, 1252L, 1253L, 1257L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `combn(nrow(df),3,FUN=function(x) df[x,],simplify=FALSE)` will give you a list of `dataframe`s with every possible combination of 3 rows.

Comment: When you say "I would need to take subsets of every 3 numbers I get in Combinations" I am slightly confused about what you mean. `Combinations` is 3 rows by 1,140 columns. Are you saying that you want the mean and sum for all 1,140 combinations?

Comment: @nicola Wow! that seems to be a great one-liner would you post an answer? Also, any advice on memory usage?